# Как заставить выходить таблицу за края родительского контейнера

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть таблица 4-мя столбцами. Все столбцы имеют одинаковую ширину. Хочу прикрутить кнопки вправо/влево на тот случай, когда таблица перестанет вмещаться по ширине в страницу, но вместо того чтобы выйти за пределы родителя (а для `td` я задал 33.333% ширину, т.е. в данном примере 4-я колонка должна уходить за пределы видимой части), в таблице обрезается ширина последней тдшки и получается примерно [такой](http://prntscr.com/ejalfi) результат. Песочница [здесь](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/EWXPde?editors=1100).

Comment: Скроллбар не устроит? Для кнопок уже нужен будет js.

Comment: @labris, не устроит) Загвоздка не в кнопках, их то я сделаю, а в том, что я описал выше)

Comment: Я смотрю, взяли вариант со скроллбаром :)

Comment: @labris, его здесь не будет) Родителю таблицы поставлю `overflow: hidden`, дальше оно будет просто листаться)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть подозрение, что ячейки нельзя сделать шире таблицы. Поэтому чтобы они выходили за пределы контейнера, ширину надо задавать самой таблице, а не ячйкам:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
table {
  width: 133.333%;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: думал о таком варианте. Минус в том, что задав ширину таблицы в 4 столбца по `33.333%` (т.е. `width` выходит `calc(100% + 33.333%)`, часть третьего столбца остается невидимой и при ресайзе ширина его отображаемой части меняется. В идеале такого быть не должно..

Comment: @Игорь, ну вот я поменял ширину на 133.333% - у меня на любом размере экрана полностью отображаются 3 ячейки. При ресайзе ничего не меняется. Или Вы что-то другое имели в виду?

Comment: нет, все верно. Сейчас у себя обновил - кажется, я где-то допустил ошибку. Благодарю вас за ответ :)

Answer (score 2):

Рабочий вариант - сломать табличную верстку:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
table {
  width:100%
}
table tr {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
table td {
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```